# How to wrap a C function whose parameters are pointer to structs, so that it can be called from Lua?

Tags: c, lua, swig

I have the follwing C function. How should I wrap it so it can be called from a Lua script?

```
typedef struct tagT{
    int a ; 
    int b ;
} type_t;

int lib_a_f_4(type_t *t)
{
     return t->a * t->b ;
}
```

I know how to wrapr it if the function parameter type were `int` or `char *`. Should I use `table` type for a C structure?

EDIT: I am using SWIG for the wraping , according to this [doc](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Lua.html), It seems that I should automatically have this function `new_type_t(2,3)` , but it is not the case.

> If you wrap a C structure, it is also
>   mapped to a Lua userdata. By adding a
>   metatable to the userdata, this
>   provides a very natural interface. For
>   example,
>
> `struct Point{   int x,y; };`
>
> is used as follows:
>
> `p=example.new_Point()`
>    `p.x=3`
>    `p.y=5`
>    `print(p.x,p.y) 3       5`
>
> Similar access is provided for unions
>   and the data members of C++ classes. C
>   structures are created using a
>   function new_Point(), but for C++
>   classes are created using just the
>   name Point().

Comment: Avoid SWIG.  It creates at least as many problems as it causes, and it is easy enough to create the API calls by hand.

Comment: @Norman: I need to wrap lots of legacy API so that I can call it from lua, so a automaic way is a MUST. Do you have any other recommendation?

Comment: How much is "lots"?  If it's less than 100 functions, you might be better off doing it by hand.  But if you want to try an automated method, `tolua` is slightly less crazy than SWIG.  Only slightly.  Even `tolua` adds a lot of unnecessary weight.  http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~celes/tolua/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put this together in a hurry. It compiled; then I did a few last-minute edits.  I hope it's close to the right thing.  Go through the Lua manual and look at all the unfamiliar functions.

```
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>

const char *metaname = "mine.type_t"; // associated with userdata of type type_t*

typedef struct tagT{
    int a ; 
    int b ;
}type_t;


int lib_a_f_4(type_t *t)
{
     return t->a * t->b ;
}

static int lua_lib_a_f_4(lua_State *L) {
  type_t *t = luaL_checkudata(L, 1, metaname);  // check argument type
  lua_pushnumber(L, (lua_Number)lib_a_f_4(t));
  return 1;
}

static int lua_new_t(lua_State *L) { // get Lua to allocate an initialize a type_t*
  int a = luaL_checkint(L, 1);
  int b = luaL_checkint(L, 2);
  type_t *t = lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(*t));
  luaL_getmetatable(L, metaname);
  lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
  t->a = a;
  t->b = b;
  return 1;
}

static const struct luaL_reg functions[] = {
  { "lib_a_f_4", lua_lib_a_f_4 },
  { "new_t", lua_new_t },
  { NULL, NULL }
};

int mylib_open(lua_State *L) {
  luaL_register(L, "mylib", functions);
  luaL_newmetatable(L, metaname);
  lua_pop(L, 1);
  return 1;
}

//compile and use it in lua
root@pierr-desktop:/opt/task/dt/lua/try1# gcc -shared -o mylib.so -I/usr/include/lua5.1/ -llua *.c -ldl
root@pierr-desktop:/opt/task/dt/lua/try1# lua
Lua 5.1.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> require("mylib")
> t=mylib.new_t(2,3)
> mylib.lib_a_f_4(t)
> print(mylib.lib_a_f_4(t))
6
>
```

Comment: Thanks. But how should i call this fuction in lua script?

Comment: You compile this function to shared library `mylib.so`, then `require` it to get a new module `mylib`.  Check out *Programming in Lua* (http://www.lua.org/pil2) or the free 1st edition.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

1. Should also add the type definition in the `example.i` file , just include the `.h` is not enough.

   ```
   %module example 
   %{
     #include "liba.h"
   %}

   void lib_a_f_1(void);
   int  lib_a_f_2(int a, int b);
   int lib_a_f_3(const char *s);
   int lib_a_f_4(struct Point *t);

   struct Point{
     int a;
     int b;
   };
   ```
2. use `example.Point()` ,not `example.new_Point()` (SWIG Version 1.3.35)

   ```
     example.Point()
     f=example.Point()
     f.a=2
     f.b=3
     example.lib_a_f_4(f)
     print(example.lib_a_f_4(f))
   ```